# .htaccess rewriterule not working for specific page

Tags: .htaccess, pattern-matching, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule which is driving me nuts. The rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=8
RewriteRule ^catalogue/index\.php$ http://www.domain.co.uk/accessories/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

which will not work for:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/catalogue/index.php?c=8
```

but this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=8
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/accessories/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

however I cannot use this script as I need to specify the catalogue/index.php so as not to rewrite other pages. Please help :(

---

Here are a few lines of code that exist before mine:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you     folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
```

Comment: The .htaccess is in the root directory, it is a opencart site and I am editing the default file.

Comment: Are there rules before this one?

Comment: There are a few which I can't see are conflicting, but I will update my post.

Comment: Only thing I see is that it's possible `/catalogue/index.php` got rewritten to `/index.php?_route_=catalogue/index.php` in the event that the `catalogue` directory doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you are right. Do you know how I can code around this?

Comment: Move your catalogue rules above the one that routes to index.php

Comment: I was wrong on this one, thank you Jon for giving me the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so people know what the solution was.

These rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

were getting applied when a request is made for `/catalogue/index.php?c=8`, and the URI is rewritten to the router: `/index.php?_route_=/catalogue/index.php`. This made it so your catalogue rule wasn't getting applied. You need to move them above the routing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=8
RewriteRule ^catalogue/index\.php$ http://www.domain.co.uk/accessories/? [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So that the redirect can take place before it gets thrown to the router.